# How to organize a game engine

Tags: c++, oop, winapi, directx, game-engine

I'm working on a small game engine and I've encountered a problem.

So far, I have a window class that is a wrapper for a Win32 window. I also have a Window Manager class (it's a singleton class) that manages the creation of windows and the handling of windows messages. I then have an engine class, which is so far the most important class, as it is the interface for the engine. This engine class contains the main loop, and the direct3d device, as well as the code to create and destroy it. This engine class also contains a Window class object, which acts as the main/host window for the direct3d device.

My problem is that the engine needs to react to some of the windows messages (such as WM_SIZE or WM_ACTIVATEAPP), but the message handler is part of the Widnow class, which is a "level" below the Engine class. I also think that I should create another class to encapsulate the rendering/graphics of the engine, and then add that class to the main engine class.

So I'm not sure whether I should have a Graphics class inside a Window class, or a Window class inside a Graphics class, or have them side by side in a main Engine class.

Comment: Suggest you outline your class structure more clearly in a visual (pseudocode) way for others to understand.

Comment: Belongs on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're living in an event-driven world, so use events. Have your window wrapper provide events that the game engine can hook and react to.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And this isn't just related to windows, you can use events for any entity-to-entity communication, like a follower walking after the main guy or whatever. That and the factory pattern (for loading, storing and accesing media) will get you far!

Answer (score 1):

Do not make the object that controls how your game engine interacts with the underlying operating system a child of the engine object. The OS layer should drive the engine, not vice versa.

(Most engines and programmers get this wrong, incidentally.)

Comment: so should I have a Framework class that controls all the other classes?

Comment: possibly a class that contains components used for graphics, input, timing, GUI etc. and will be responsible to initialize all of these components, as well as control the communication between them.

Comment: You certainly could do that. It's a bit of overkill since it's usually easier to setup a complicated graph of objects explicitly.

Comment: @Zayats, it's a lot easier to set up `main()` to create your game engine and os binding layer explicitly than to hide it behind a framework.

Answer (score 1):

Will you ever have multiple Windows? Increasingly, multi-monitor is getting more use for a variety of games.

Will you ever run multiple Graphics on one Window? Pretty unlikely. That suggests to me that Window should be in Graphics, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes sense when you think about it, but can you use one device for multiple windows?

Comment: @Zayats: You certainly can. Some games like Supreme Commander natively support two windows.